# Program gets stuck after taking screenshot

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, gdi+

```
#include "screenshot.h"
#include "changewallpaper.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    screenshot();
    changewallpaper();
}
```

My screenshot();

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

int GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
   UINT  num = 0;          // number of image encoders
   UINT  size = 0;         // size of the image encoder array in bytes

   ImageCodecInfo* pImageCodecInfo = NULL;

   GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
   if(size == 0)
      return -1;  // Failure

   pImageCodecInfo = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
   if(pImageCodecInfo == NULL)
      return -1;  // Failure

   GetImageEncoders(num, size, pImageCodecInfo);

   for(UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
   {
      if( wcscmp(pImageCodecInfo[j].MimeType, format) == 0 )
      {
         *pClsid = pImageCodecInfo[j].Clsid;
         free(pImageCodecInfo);
         return j;  // Success
      }
   }

   free(pImageCodecInfo);
   return -1;  // Failure
}

void screenshot()
{
    // get the device context of the screen
    HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);

    int width = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
    int height = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

    POINT a,b;

    a.x=0;
    a.y=0;

    b.x=width;
    b.y=height;

    // copy screen to bitmap
    HDC     hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC     hDC     = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, abs(b.x-a.x), abs(b.y-a.y));
    HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
    BOOL    bRet    = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, abs(b.x-a.x), abs(b.y-a.y), hScreen, a.x, a.y, SRCCOPY);

    //Initialize GDI+
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);

    CLSID pngClsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
    bitmap.Save(L"D:\\Pictures\\screen.png", &pngClsid, NULL);

    // clean up
    SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hScreen);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);

    //delete image;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

My problem is that  changewallpaper(); never runs. If I place changewallpaper(); before screenshot(); in my main everything works but not if I have it like above. I need my program to take the screenshot before it changes the wallpaper so I can't just switch them. Does anyone know what might be the problem? I am clueless.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it’s not working in the current order — is it hanging? Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger to see how far it gets in `screenshot()`?  If screenshot is returning successfully, the problem could be in the other function (which is not part of the question right now).

Comment: Please show the code for `changewallpaper`

Comment: GDI+ uses WIC, an interface exposed through COM. Presumably, GDI+ initializes COM on the calling thread. If it chooses a single-threaded apartment, you need to run a message loop.

Comment: @IInspectable, assuming you tried my fix and it still hangs could you tell me where it hangs? I'd like to try and learn from this. In the debugger after scoping gdi object I can see all three GDI threads exit cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @xsoftie, You are hanging in the `image::~image()`.

According to the [GdiplusShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusshutdown#remarks) :

> you must delete all of your GDI+ objects (or have them go out of
>   scope) before you call GdiplusShutdown.

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);
```

`bitmap` are stored on the stack, and the system automatically releases them at the end of their life cycle (after {}). scoftie's method is one of feasible solutions.

Of course you can also use `new` to request GDI + object pointers on the heap, as this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusinit/nf-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartup#examples):

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap *bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);
CLSID pngClsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
bitmap->Save(L"D:\\Pictures\\screen.png", &pngClsid, NULL);

//...
delete bitmap;
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

Or, put `GdiplusStartup` and `GdiplusShutdown` in the main function:

```
int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    screenshot();
    changewallpaper();
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

And in addition, When you no longer need the `hScreenDC`, call the `DeleteDC` function.

Answer (score 0):

A couple changes. The scoping is necessary to get the bitmap out of scope and clean up after itself. The second is releasing the hScreenDC although I'll leave that as an exercise for you to see if it is necessary. You were hanging in the image::~image function. Let me know if it fixes it for you.

```
  {
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);

    CLSID pngClsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
    bitmap.Save(L"c:\\temp\\screen.png", &pngClsid, NULL);
}

// clean up
SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
DeleteDC(hDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hScreen);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
DeleteDC(hScreenDC);
```